# Jquery lightbox form submitting

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a form in which the user can enter fields and click a button to send the submitted data to a php script which adds the data to the database.

The issue is that the data isnt all being sent.

The code:

```
$(document).on("click" ,".save_new_user",function() {
    var form_data = {
        "first_name"    : $(".first_name").val(),
        "last_name"     : $(".last_name").val(),
        "email"         : $(".email").val(),
        "username"      : $(".username").val(),
        "auth_level"    : $(".auth_level").find(":selected").text()
    };

    console.log(form_data);

    var request = $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajax/create_user.php",
        data: form_data,
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The markup:

```
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" class="first_name">
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" class="last_name">
Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" class="email">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" class="username">
Auth Level: <select class="auth_level"><option>Admin</option><option>Editor</option></select>
<div class="save_new_user">Add User</div>
```

The console log of form_data returns the following even when the form is filled in:
Array
(
    [first_name] => 
    [last_name] => 
    [email] => 
    [username] => 
    [auth_level] => Admin
)

Please help!

Comment: i ve tested it in a fiddle and it works fine https://jsfiddle.net/csdrn54t/ (nothing changed from your code )

Comment: There must be something else interfering then hmmm. Thanks!

Comment: there is other event handler on that class??

Answer (score 0):

This works a charm (I have replaced `class` with `id`):

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>    
  <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).on("click" ,".save_new_user",function() {
                    var form_data = {
                        "first_name"    : $("#first_name").val(),
                        "last_name"     : $("#last_name").val(),
                        "email"         : $("#email").val(),
                        "username"      : $("#username").val(),
                        "auth_level"    : $("#auth_level").find(":selected").text()
                    };

                    console.log(form_data);
          });
/*
            var request = $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "ajax/create_user.php",
                data: form_data,
            })
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
            });*/
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"/>
Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
Auth Level: <select id="auth_level"><option>Admin</option><option>Editor</option></select>
<input type="button" class="save_new_user" value="Add User"></input>

</body>
</html>
```